# Getting a unique identifier from a browser

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm upping my security on my website, because some of my users were
questioning the security, but all I can say is no one can view your
password (dual hashed using SHA-512 and then md5), but they reply, but what if they get into my account they
can change my password and play around with my account.

So I'm going to up my security kind of like Steam's security where you can't login to a
new computer without them sending you a random key. I'm trying to think of a way to do it, so I've got it so it will store a little array in my database that will have all the computers that the user has logged in to with.

But I need some data so that my script can check it but I'm not quite sure what data, I was thinking of the IP address but you can't get it without an external source e.g  [whats my ip](http://whatismyipaddress.com/)  and other sites like that. I need some data that doesn't change with the same browser/computer.

So question is, I need some data that is unique to the browser he/she is using but it does change if he/she is on a different computer or browser.

Comment: `upping my security on my website`???

Comment: How about usernames and passwords?

Comment: no like something that is unique to the computer/browser like a ip address is and @Mr.Alien whats wrong with that??

Comment: Before you make further security improvements, tell us how the user passwords are stored. This should give us an idea if you should be doing this at all.

Comment: it is store in a database :-D, but they are hashed with sha-512 and will be encrypted with a 128-bit encryption when I get the funds to do so

Comment: Are they salted, or just hashed? Why do you think adding encryption will help?

Comment: @NullUserException just hashed

Comment: This doesn't inspire much confidence that you know what you're doing. 1) Passwords should *always* be salted. 2) Why aren't you using a designed password hashing function like bcrypt instead of a general purpose (ie: fast) hashing function like SHA?

Comment: well whats a good tut for bcyript and im salting the passwords and stuff atm :-D

Comment: @NullUserException Sorry its dual hashed through sha-512 fist and then md5

Comment: You know what *I* would do? Just defer authentication to the folks who are experts in this: Google, Facebook, Yahoo, etc. Kind of like what Stack Overflow does. I love the convenience of having fewer passwords to memorize, too.

Comment: @Ryanc1256 That's another sign that you don't know what you're doing. Don't "dual hash," it doesn't add any security to the scheme and could actually make it worse. Read this post: http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: yer Im not a security guru, so i know a little but not much :-D so yer thanks a lot

Comment: @Ryanc1256 Number 1 rule in crypto is, doing invent your own crypto. You might also want to check out our security site (http://security.stackexchange.com/), where you might get better answers for questions like this one. You'll probably also find a few questions and answers where you can learn from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to implement some security in your web application on IP level. As a matter a fact, for example, in the company I am working it's possible to log in with "Administrator" account only from the devices connected in company network - a given range of IP address.

If you want to implement this technique for each user, you will meet a lot of issues because your users can be behind some proxy server, that is changing their IP address on each log in or on given interval of time.

They are different [types](http://info.webtoolhub.com/kb-a14-types-of-proxy-servers-transparent-and-anonymous-proxies.aspx) of proxies and you can detect when the user is using some of them, and then retrieve the real IP address of the user - check this HTTP headers:[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, HTTP_VIA AND REMOTE_ADDR EXPLAINED](http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2011/08/http_x_forwarded_for-http_via-and-remote_addr-explained/) and more specific this [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) one.

Any way, they are a lot of techniques to hide you IP address like proxy servers and applications like [HideMyAss](http://www.hidemyass.com/) that makes the whole thing pretty easy.

Anyway, even your users send to you a specific set of email address that you will store in your database and check if the users are connected to your application using them, the same possibility for abuse, using your account (as the passwords) is faced again. The IP addresses will be just an other field in your database table. So, if anyone can change the  passwords, he might be able to add an other new IP to the IP list that your are checking.

I think that the best think to do, is to implement such IP security only for your administrator account. Then, you and your clients will be calm that no one can join with it and change their passwords.

Comment: very interesting :-P, I thought of that but it was a small possibly that they hack into the server and add there ip address (if he knows what he is doing presuming that he does)

Comment: You can simply remove the "change password" option from your administrator's panel, and leave it as option for your users only via their mail addresses.

Comment: yes, I just want to make sure my clients security is fine but I am just going to change the hashing algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you have many users, I never did this in a practical application but played with bouncycastle a long time ago. Had a similar problem with a 3rd party provider providing services to out company with IP filtering but Dubai offices were refused because some proxy gets in there that doesn't provide forwarded for and has a wide IP range.

Here is the option I was thinking of but never applied:

Making a self signed key for each/all/groups of client to import and and importing the public part of that in your server store, then do not allow anybody there unless they have a key that's imported in your server keystore.

Maybe if you serve companies that use a proxy you can have the proxy serve the key.